# Loading a csv file

Tags: mysql

I was trying to load a csv file into a table called `Actors`.
What is the problem with this code?

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'actors.csv'
INTO TABLE Actors
FIELD TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"';
```

Comment: How about you tell us what the problem with the code is?

Comment: I got an error called: ERROR 1064(42000) You have an error in your SQL syntax @ line 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with syntax.

Please refer to the [MySQL Manual - 13.2.6 LOAD DATA INFILE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html).  The correct syntax is `FIELDS` not `FIELD`.

Therefore it should be:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'actors.csv'
INTO TABLE Actors
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"';
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried FIELDS, but still get the same error.

Comment: There aren't any syntax issues in the code above so I find it hard to believe you're still getting a syntax error. Please visit the MySQL manual page I've linked to and read it - everything you need to know about `LOAD DATA` is contained within

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, ignore the last line if you don't have header(heading columns) at top of csv file

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'actors.csv' 
INTO TABLE Actors
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
```